# How to add different CSS for galleries

Tags: plugins, filters, css

I use jetpack carousel for all of my galleries , even for my featured image, my question is, how do I style my [gallery] outcome to use different CSS for the featured image so I can manipulate it a little bit but not mess with the regular default galleries outcome?

Comment: no one? :( ....

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is open it up in chrome, inspect element, and check to see if the featured image has a different ID or CLASS to the other images in the gallery. Then I would add an additional line to my CSS that targets those ID/CLASS.

In the event that a ID/CLASS aren't unique I would be looking into inspecting the plugin, and adding my own declaration (strongest thing in wordpress for me is that a lot of elements have classes/id's)

If you need further detailed help, I'm happy to edit this answer in future just let me know.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the image does have a different ID than the rest, but even when I specify a special css for it, it doesnt work because when you click on the link, it launches extra overlay code that was not present before :(

Comment: @user1231517, please, add these details to the Question itself, as you don't mention any "extra overlay" code in it.

Comment: This is a really quick hack, but try adding the clause !imporant, its usage is like this,

#featured-item { width:100px !important;}